# JSF Primefaces v5.1: sorting/filtering fails when other page is included inside c:if

Tags: sorting, jsf, datatable, primefaces, filtering

I am using primefaces 5.1

I have a dropdown. Based on the value selected in the dropdown, my application should insert another xhtml file. Anotherfile1,2 has datatable which i want to sort or filter as well.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="basic"......
.....
<f:ajax render="@form" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

So when I use like below, sort/filter is not working and throwing the exception below.

```
<c:if test="#{myBackBean.name eq'X'}" >
    <ui:include src="subdir/anotherfile1.xhtml"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{myBackBean.name eq'Y'}" >
    <ui:include src="subdir/anotherfile2.xhtml"/>
</c:if>
```

*com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException*

If i use the below code, everything works. But I dont want to do this as its loading all the backbeans in the beginning itself which slows downs the performance.

```
<p:panel id= "id1" rendered="#{myBackBean.name eq'X'}">
  <ui:include src="subdir/anotherfile1.xhtml"/>
</p:panel>
<p:panel id= "id2" rendered="#{myBackBean.name eq'Y'}">
  <ui:include src="subdir/anotherfile2.xhtml"/>
</p:panel>
```

with c:if performace is good but sort/filter is not working. All the data in the datatable disappears. Can someone help please.

Comment: So try pf 6 or 6.1 ir 6.2 or 7 or 8

Comment: Oh and post full stacktraces not just errors and even better try to analyze them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors. And try with a `p:ajax` or with a `h:selectOneMenu` with `f:ajax`... And also [mcve]/

Comment: We cannot upgrade the version now. Also I see only pasted lines in the catalina log. Dont see any other stack. Will try p:ajax, h:selectOneMenu and update here.

Comment: TRY with a [mcve]. I nowhere stated you should upgrade the application. But knowing it works in newer versions is relevant info that you can use to see if you can create a workaround based on the newer source or if you do want start upgrading. Now you are asking US to do do work. And "Don't see any other stack" is a weird comment. It is a stacktrace and it ALWAYS consists of waaaay more info than this single line...